# Using Python split to splice a variable together

Tags: python, split

I have this list

```
["camilla_farnestam@hotmail.com : martin00", ""],
```

How do I split so it only be left with:

```
camilla_farnestam@hotmail.com:martin00
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to have: `aList[0]` ?

**EDIT::**
Oh, you have a tuple with the list in it!
Now I see:

```
al = ["camilla_farnestam@hotmail.com : martin00", ""],
#type(al) == tuple
#len(al) == 1
aList = al[0]
#type(aList) == list
#len(aList) == 2
#Now you can type:
aList[0]
#and you get:
"camilla_farnestam@hotmail.com : martin00"
```

You can use `aList[0].replace(' : ', ':')` if you wish to remove spaces before and after colon, suit your needs.
I think that the most confusing thing here is the coma ending the first line. It creates a new tuple, that contains your list.

Answer (score 3):

```
al = ["camilla_farnestam@hotmail.com : martin00", ""],
print al[0][0].replace(" : ", ":")
```

Answer (score 2):

comma at the end means that list is first member of a tuple, but to your question:

```
in_list = ["camilla_farnestam@hotmail.com : martin00", ""]
result = ''.join(in_list[0].split(' '))
```

Answer (score 1):

Exactly.

```
    $ python
    Python 2.6 (r26:66714, Dec  4 2008, 11:34:15) 
    [GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5488)] on darwin
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> al = ["camilla_farnestam@hotmail.com : martin00", ""]
    >>> print al[0]
    camilla_farnestam@hotmail.com : martin00
    >>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Abgan, is probably correct, although if you still want a list, ie.,

```
["camilla_farnestam@hotmail.com : martin00"]
```

you'd want:

```
the_list[:1]
```

Comment: The question suprised me so much, that I posted only the most obvious answer. I'm beginning to doubt if there is really no too newbie questions ;-)

Comment: I was not correct. He was creating a tuple with a list inside, so he needed to do al[0][0] to retrieve the actual string. See the comma ending the first line of his code?

Comment: I see it now. It didn't click that it was indicated a tuple, I just figured it was part of his sentence structure :P

Answer (score 0):

lists can be accessed by index or sliced into smaller lists.
http://diveintopython3.ep.io/native-datatypes.html